# cosh and log in MatLab

Tags: matlab, logging, trigonometry, ln

I'm new to MatLab and for the sake of an exercise for my university I have to find a root using Newton's method for a given function.

```
>> x = linspace(-3,3);
>> y = sinh(x-1)*log((3+2)*x+1)-1-1;
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

>> y = sinh(x-1).*log((3+2)*x+1)-1-1;
>> plot(x,y)
Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored
```

I wanted to visualize my function but as you can see in the first error I can't use the standard * operator so I tried with .* (which I can't really understand what it does) but the graph was far from right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first error "Error using  * Inner matrix dimensions must agree.":
In Matlab `A*A` is not the same as `A.*A`. The first method is general Matrix Multiplication and the second is element wise multiplication. In your case `sinh(x-1)` will create a matrix of size [1 100] and `log((3+2)*x+1)` will create a matrix with the same size (because `x` has this size). The matrix product however is not possible([1 100] *[1 100]).

For the second question I agree with mpaskov and just want to add that you can specify only the real part with `real(y)`.

Comment: sorry if it is a stupid question but, why it is not possible? I mean, they are the same dimentions, don't they?

Comment: Ahh sorry I haven't seen your message.
they have the same dimension of [1 100] but the matrix product is defined for: [m n] x [n o]
You see the 2nd dimension of Matrix 1 and 1st dimension of Matrix 2 have to be equal...which is not the case in your example

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to plot complex numbers. `log` of a negative number is complex.

You can try to plot the `abs` value:

```
plot(x,abs(y));
```

or try plotting `y` on a complex plane (x-axis is real number y-axis imaginary).

```
plot(y, 'o');
```

depending on what you are after.